# Insert SQL Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert, vba, exists

I am trying to insert two fields into one access table from another but I only want to insert the fields for the records that exist in both tables.  I have started developing a SQL statement which I have pasted below but I am unsure of the syntax for the exists statement.  I basically want to say where FormularyID Exists in "MyTable". Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable (FormularyName, ClientName)
SELECT [Formulary Name], [Client Name]
FROM FN_DataDump_ALL_02012015
WHERE EXISTS (
```

TEST DATA:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H35wm.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Just put another SELECT statement in there to return the records you want to check:

```
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT FormularyID FROM MyTable WHERE SomeCondition
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the exists operator write the select from the table you want to check in where clause join the common columns in both the tables Try this.

```
INSERT INTO ShouldImportMetricsIDsTable
            (FormularyName,ClientName)
SELECT [Formulary Name],
       [Client Name]
FROM   FN_DataDump_ALL_02012015 as F
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   mytable as M
               WHERE  F.formularyId = M.formularyId)
```

Comment: It asks me to define the parameter "`F.formularyId`" Shouldn't there be an "as" in `FN_DataDump_ALL_02012015 F`?

Comment: This works but it inserts them as new records.  I would like to add the field values to the records that already exists.  How would I do that?

Comment: @peter burke sorry didn't get you can you add sample data and expected output

Comment: I have Added a picture of my table to the question.  This is what that SQL Query does.  It adds the information as new records.  I want to add them to the records that already exist.  Would that be possible? Maybe with an `UPDATE` Statement?